# Stackless Scala play framework runtime error

Tags: scala, akka

I got this cute error, that has no stack trace associated with it in play's log file (nor in the console).

```
[ERROR] [03/14/2015 19:36:46.713] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [ActorSystem(play)] Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] (scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl)
[error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7]
scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl: null
```

Does this represent a promise/future that crashed, but has no thread any longer waiting for it other than akka's dispatcher? how can I nonetheless trace the error in my code without attaching a debugger session?

Attaching a debugger, it seems that using a `return` inside Future `map` composition caused the `NonLocalReturnControl` error. Oddly and unfortunately though, the stack trace doesn't propagate to the console/log in this case in my case. The stack at the moment a NonLocalReturnControl is created can be seen in a debugger, but akka/play somehow don't provide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alas, this type of error's stack trace is suppressed by default. Turns out quite amazingly that scala internally implements function return value propagation by internally throwing and catching this exception type (up until Scala 2.11 at least). Hence the special suppression... Tough luck.

The same exception arises when using `return` in a future, which is obviously a mistake, but the internal architecture's use of this suppressed exception, makes debugging this particular case, well, suck. Check you don't use `return` in asynchronous code if you get this error, and avoid using `return` as much as you can so it is less likely this will pop up in your code when turned asynchronous.

Comment: Note that normally NoStackTrace lets you set a system property in order to see the stack traces, but `return` specially ignores the property for performance reasons: https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/270c0cb80df85b613cfa3e5f85f70cf1f35e2388, making debugging especially hard.

Comment: Thanks for the comment